# Is it possible to define a special sort key in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting

I have a MongoDB collection that I want to display on a webpage using pymongo and flask. I want to display only N at a time on the webpage, but I don't want to load the entire set at once, sort, and then show entries a:(a+N).

What I'd like to do is something like

```
db.jobs.find().sort({{"status" : KEY, "startTime" : -1})).skip(a).limit(N)
```

Values in status would be "UNENDED", "SUCCESS", "FAILED". And I want to be able to define the sort order.

Normally in python I'd do something like:

```
_JOB_PRIORITIES = {"UNDENDED" : 0, "SUCCESS" : 1, "FAILURE" : 2}
jobs = sorted((job for job in jobs),key=lambda j: _JOB_PRIORITIES.get(j["result"]))
```

But as I said, I'd rather not load everything into the program, but rather have MongoDB do all of that work.

Is such a thing possible in MongoDB, or am I going to have to define some "statusPriority" field when I create the entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add the statusPriority field to your documents like you have defined in _JOB_PRIORITIES and then sort on that in the Mongo cursor.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/